# Add custom flow on member registration form in Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordpress website and want to add custom flow of registration. [image]

The current website has these pages but I am not sure if there is any `plugin` that has inbuilt such flow feature or how to add this feature.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a similar modification.
Your case seems the same as mine, its  a single form, split onto steps for helping users/validations.
I didn't found any plugin ready for all i needed (the steps thing), and mainly ... hooks to change registration form in wordpress just add extra fields to standard fields, i needed to completly remix the order, so I went the javascript way:

- Added my custom css and JS to login/register pages with the action 'login_enqueue_scripts'
- Added my custom fields to form using 'register_form' action
- Added a class to login body with 'login_body_class' filter, to keep things hidden while JS magic happened;

I'm not sure what's your skill level in JS, but once you got those hooks ready you can make pretty much whatever you want with the register form.